# Not able to pass String value through Bundle

Tags: android, string, android-fragments, bundle

This question is something serious for me , i need to someone help me regarding this. Actually i am creating an RSS feed app by combining navigation drawer and view pager tabbed activity. i want to pass a string value from one fragment to other fragment. here is the thing. It was working properly when it was with the navigation drawer activity but after combining with view-pager , String is not passing to other fragment through bundle, i can't find the error because its not showing any error,

This is from i am passing string

```
public class RssFragment extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener {


private ProgressBar progressBar;
private ListView listView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_first, container, false);
    progressBar = (ProgressBar) view.findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
    listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    startService();
}

private void startService() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), RssService.class);
    getActivity().startService(intent);
}

/**
 * Once the {@link RssService} finishes its task, the result is sent to this BroadcastReceiver
 */
private BroadcastReceiver resultReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        List<RssItem> items = (List<RssItem>) intent.getSerializableExtra(RssService.ITEMS);
        if (items != null) {
            RssAdapter adapter = new RssAdapter(getActivity(), items);
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "An error occurred while downloading the rss feed.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    }
};

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    RssAdapter adapter = (RssAdapter) parent.getAdapter();
    RssItem item = (RssItem) adapter.getItem(position);


    Uri uri = Uri.parse(item.getDescription());
    String string;
    string=uri.toString();



    result Des_1=new result();
    FragmentManager fragmentManager1 =getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.content_main_layout_frame,Des_1 ).addToBackStack("fragBack").commit();



    result ldf = new result();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("YourKey", string);
    ldf.setArguments(args);
    getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.content_main_layout_frame, ldf).commit();

}

@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(RssService.ACTION_RSS_PARSED);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).registerReceiver(resultReceiver, intentFilter);
}

@Override
public void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getActivity()).unregisterReceiver(resultReceiver);
}
}
```

This is how i am receiving the string

```
public class result extends Fragment {


public result() {


    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result,container,false);

    Bundle bundle = getArguments();

    TextView textView=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.distext);





    if(bundle != null) {

        String value = bundle.getString("YourKey");

        textView.setText(value);

      //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), value,
            //   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }





    return rootview;
}

}
```

I pleasing someone to figure it out. i repeat it was working but now its not

It is another fragment

```
public class datafragment extends Fragment {
View view;
ViewPager viewPager;
TabLayout tabLayout;


@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view= inflater.inflate(R.layout.sample,container,false);


    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new sliderAdapter(getChildFragmentManager()));
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.sliding_tabs);
    tabLayout.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
        }
    });

    return view;

}




private class sliderAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter{

    final  String tabs[]={"tab1", "tab2","tab3"};
    public sliderAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }


    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        Fragment fragment = null;
        switch (position){
            case 0:
                fragment = new RssFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                fragment = new RssFragment();
                break;
            case 2:
                fragment = new RssFragment();
                break;
        }
        return fragment;
    }


    @Override
    public int getCount() {


       return 3;
    }
   @Override
   public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return tabs[position];
   }
}




}
```

Comment: First of all change the name of your String object from string to anything else please

Comment: changed.........................

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below one,

```
ldf = new result(); 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
bundle.putString("key","value");
ldf.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragBack");
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.content_main_layout_frame, ldf);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove both the transaction and add the below code instead,

```
ldf = new result(); 
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = 
getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
bundle.putString("key","value");
ldf.setArguments(bundle);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack("fragBack");
fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.content_main_layout_frame, ldf);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Let me know if that helps!

Comment: can you tell me why it happend?

Comment: since there was two transaction sequentially, the first transaction i.e, the one with out bundle params gets executed and opened the fragment. The code after that does not effective.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
public class result extends Fragment {


public result() {


// Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                     Bundle savedInstanceState) {
View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_result,container,false);

TextView textView=(TextView)rootview.findViewById(R.id.distext);


if(savedInstanceState!= null) {

    String value = savedInstanceState.getString("YourKey");

    textView.setText(value);

  //  Toast.makeText(getActivity(), value,
        //   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}

return rootview;
}

}
```